# Question on a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $x:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ a solution of the differenzial equation:

$$5x′′(t)+ 10x′(t)+ 6x(t)=0$$

Proof that the function:

$$f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$$

defined by:

$$f(t) =\frac{x(t)^2}{1 +x(t)^4}$$

has maximal value.

I don't know how to begin the excercise, can someone help me pls?

Comment: Yes, @ThomasAndrews I was wrong

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean by “defined by $f(t)=\dots.$” if you mean “with the condition that $f(t)$ is maximal,” then it isn’t clear what it means to be a maximal function.

Comment: I concur with Thomas. What role does $f$ play here, and what does it mean for it to be maximal? The question is confusing.

Comment: Thanks for correction @ThomasAndrews

Comment: It seems like $\sup_t f(t)=+\infty$ for all but one solution  $x(t), $ so, again, the maximum condition is still confusing.

Comment: I have no idea what this question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined as follows:

$$y(t)=\frac{t^2}{1+t^4}$$

Consider that $x$ exists; $x(t)=e^{-t} \left(A\cos\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt5}\right)+B\cos\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt5}\right)\right)$ fulfills the differential equation. Consider also that

$$f(t) = y(x(t))\text.$$

Now calculate the first and second derivatives of $y$:

$$y'(t)=\frac{2t(1+t^4)-t^2(4t^3)}{(1+t^4)^2}$$
$$y'(t)=\frac{2t(1-t^4)}{(1+t^4)^2}=\frac{2t(1-t^2)(1+t^2)}{(1+t^4)^2}$$

and

$$y''(t)=\frac{(2-10t^4)(1+2t^4+t^8)-(2t-2t^5)(8t^7+8t^3)}{(1+t^4)^4}$$
$$y''(t)=\frac{2+4t^4+2t^8-10t^4-20t^8-10t^{12}+16t^{12}+16t^8-16t^8-16t^4}{(1+t^4)^4}$$
$$y''(t)=\frac{2-22t^4-18t^8+6t^{12}}{(1+t^4)^4}$$
$$y''(t)=\frac{2(1+t^4)(1-12t^4+3t^8)}{(1+t^4)^4}$$
$$y''(t)=\frac{2(1-12t^4+3t^8)}{(1+t^4)^3}$$

Consider that the stationary points of $y$ (points where $y'(t)=0$) are $-1,0,1$ and of those points, only $-1$ and $1$ yield negative values for the second derivative. Therefore the points making $y$ maximal are $-1$ and $1$.

Now it only remains to prove that $x(t)$ reaches the value $-1$ or $1$ somewhere on $\mathbb{R}$, which should be fairly easy (with the intermediate value theorem). After that is proven, you have a maximal value of $f$, which is $\frac12$.

Exception: if $A=B=0$, then $x(t)$ does not reach $-1$ or $1$, but $f$ becomes constant and thus has a maximum.

Comment: Can you explain pls what is the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: The intermediate value theorem states: if $f$ is continuous in the interval $[a,b]$, then for every real number $r$ such that $r$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ (that is, $f(a)\lt r\lt f(b)$ or $f(b)\lt r\lt f(a)$), then there exist a point $c$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(c)=r$.